# How to create dialogue for a chat bot in Python?

Tags: python, chatbot

I want to write a quick and simple chat bot that can carry a dialogue with a user. I want to know how to create dialogue that allows for possibly an infinite amount of **inputs** and **responses**. Right now the code I'm working with doesn't allow for user defined input. This is the code that I'm working with now.

```
# Import the random module
import random

bot_template = "AGENT: {0}"
user_template = "USER: {0}"

# Define variables
name = "Greg"
weather = "cloudy"

# Define a dictionary containing a list of responses for each message
responses = {
  "what's your name?": [
      "my name is {0}".format(name),
      "they call me {0}".format(name),
      "I go by {0}".format(name)
   ],
  "what's today's weather?": [
      "the weather is {0}".format(weather),
      "it's {0} today".format(weather)
    ],
  "default": ["default message"]
}

# Use random.choice() to choose a matching response
def respond(message):
    # Check if the message is in the responses
    if message in responses:
        # Return a random matching response
        bot_message = random.choice(responses[message])
    else:
        # Return a random "default" response
        bot_message = random.choice(responses["default"])
    return bot_message

# Define a function that sends a message to the bot: send_message
def send_message(message):
    # Print user_template including the user_message
    print(user_template.format(message))
    # Get the bot's response to the message
    response = respond(message)
    # Print the bot template including the bot's response.
    print(bot_template.format(response))

# Send a message to the bot
send_message("what's today's weather?")
```

Comment: you can get user input as described here: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/getting-user-input-from-the-keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
# Send a message to the bot
send_message("what's today's weather?")
```

You can write:

```
while True:
    print('Write your message to the bot and press ENTER')
    user_msg = input()

    # Send a message to the bot
    send_message(user_msg)
```

This will send entered by user messages to the bot until you stop the program.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you know if there's a way to print "user_msg" just once. Right now in the command line it prints twice.                                                                                                                       Write your message to the bot and press ENTER
what's your name?
USER: what's your name?
AGENT: I go by Greg
Write your message to the bot and press ENTER

Comment: @greymatter Isn't this line of code prints it: `print(user_template.format(message))`?

Comment: Thanks  it worked. One more thing. Do you know if there's a way  to begin the line "what's your name?" with input  "USER:"

Comment: @greymatter glad it worked, will appreciate very much if you accept my answer :) As for your question if I understand correctly, you need to change `input()` to  `input('USER: ')`

Comment: @greymatter you're welcome! please accept my answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [input()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp) command allows you to get user defined strings. It returns a string containing the line a user typed into the shell running the program.